# Ode equation how to solve them.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

[enter link description here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29=%20%7Cy%28x%29%7C,%20x%20from%201%20to%20100)

I have function y' = |y|. Could you explain me how to solve Ode quation step-by-step without using complicated mathematical things. It is easy for me when i knew that y = f(x). But i dont knew how to solve on my own equation like that. I read a lot of articles on the internet but they are to hard and general. I am not studying math so this is hard for me to understand.
If this function is to hard you can show me something simpler. I saw some examples but i could solve them on my own only check that result is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y' = |y|$$
Separating variables:
$$\frac{dy}{|y|dx} = 1$$ (assuming y is a function of $x$ and dividing each side by $|y|$)
$$\int \frac{dy}{|y|dx}dx = \int 1 dx$$ (integrating both sides with respect to $x$)
$$\int \frac{dy}{|y|} = \int 1dx$$ (cancelling dx's)
$$ln|y| = x + C$$ (computing integrals)
$$|y| = e^{x+C}$$ (taking exponentials of both sides)
$$|y| = Ae^x$$  (since $e^{x+C} = e^Ce^x$ and substituting $A = e^C$)

Comment: thx it was fast.. I am not good at guessing. I would love to solve this without this but what i learned that ODE sometimes we need to solve by guesing

Comment: yes: just learning what other people found!

Comment: actually it might not work. If you plug -3 into $y = e^{|-x|}$ you get $y = e^{|-3|} = e^3 \ne e^-3 = e^x$- sorry

Comment: ignore last comment and see edited answer

Comment: An ode usually has more than one solution.

Comment: Yes. I realised upon reflection that the answer was wrong. I've just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint, solve the problem in pieces based on the sign of $y$ (there are other approaches too), that is:

- For $y \ge 0$, solve $y' = y \rightarrow \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{y} = \int dx$
- For $y \lt 0$, solve $y' = -y \rightarrow \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{y} = - \int dx$

Can you solve either of those integrals and then find $y(x)$?

Comment: Needs another TU! +1

Comment: Halloween's a-comin' in no time... 8)